# Laravel Make Auth, hide register behind auth?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-artisan

So I recently decided to try the command

```
php artisan make:auth
```

instead of creating all of the auth myself, it seemed to work and I continued on with my app. However now I am at the point in my app where I do not want a public facing register page (I want this to be admin only to add new users). However the command does not insert individual routes or functions, it is something built into laravel. So normally I could just use

```
$this->middleware('auth');
```

inside of the controller that handled the register, but since that is the same controller as the login it causes problems....Does anyone know a way to keep the register page created by php artisan make:auth behind the login wall so only admins can register new users?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes and https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#controller-middleware have all you need.

Comment: My issue was that those documents do not address the issue of the built in auth commands. I do not know how to edit or alter any of the existing routes setup by the php artisan make:auth command. For example doing something like this 
Route::get('register', ['middleware' => 'auth', function () {
    //
}]);
Does nothing at all.

Comment: it causes no problem. The constructor guest middleware need to handle login/logout. You can do apply auth middleware from where you define routes see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First: cancel the current route for registering users. (There are several ways to do so) ex: get ride of Route::auth(); from route.php and only apply what routes you want to apply. auth() defined in router.php as following:

```
/**
 * Register the typical authentication routes for an application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function auth()
{
    // Authentication Routes...
    $this->get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
    $this->post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
    $this->get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    $this->get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
    $this->post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');

    // Password Reset Routes...
    $this->get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
    $this->post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
    $this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@reset');
}
```

Second: create your own route with middleware Auth applied ex:

```
Route::get('users/create', [
    'middleware' => 'auth', 
    'as' => 'users.create', 
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@create'
]);
```

you can apply the middleware in diffrent ways see this link for more:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-group-middleware

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-change-the-code-for-the-built-in-authentication-in-laravel) it seems that you should be able to create your own Auth controller which uses the `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait, and then override the [`getRegister` and `postRegister`](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.html) methods.

Something like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application registration form.
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getRegister()
    {
        // show register view
    }

    /**
     * Handle a registration request for the application.
     * @return Response
     */
    public function postRegister(Request $request)
    {
        // register logic
    }

}
```